# PySide Widget grabbing keyboard, blocks MainWindow with MenuBar from being moved on raspbian

Tags: python, pyside, raspbian, menubar

i got a main window in PySide2 on Raspbian. The window contains a QLineEdit, which grabs the keyboard, and a menu bar with a single menu/action. When starting the app everything works fine. But as soon as i click on the menu in the menubar i'm not able to move the window on the desktop anymore.
When i do not grab the keyboard it works as expected.

On Windows everything seems to work fine even if i grab the keyboard.
Is there a problem with the code or is this a bug? Are there any work arounds?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QLineEdit

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        menu = self.menuBar()
        start_menu = menu.addMenu("Start")

        action = QAction("Test", self)
        action.triggered.connect(self.test)
        start_menu.addAction(action)

        line_edit = QLineEdit()
        line_edit.grabKeyboard()

        self.setCentralWidget(line_edit)

    def test(self):
        print("clicked")

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QApplication()

    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Why are you using `grabKeyboard()`?

Comment: In the real program i'm having a barcode scanner and a virtual numpad on a touchscreen that enters a barcode in the lineedit. When it receives an Enter from either the scanner or the virtual keyboard a background thread is started. By hitting a stop button on the screen the thread finishes. When finished it should be possible to start the process again without giving the focus to the lineedit again. So the user should have minimal workload by just scanning the barcode or entering the code manual and hitting the start button.

Comment: Mmh. Barcode scanners act as keyboards, but they should not completely grab keyboard events for the system, especially if the UI has to accept *other* input events. Maybe you should install an event filter on the program instead and filter for keyboard events, instead of completely grabbing keyboard events (which might result in unexpected behavior): since the program is likely going to be the *main* program for the whole interface, you shouldn't expect keyboard events for other widgets, as soon as they are catched by the application event filter.

Comment: Hmm ok. The virtual numpad is realized with pynput simulating the keys. And for now there are no other widgets expecting a keyboard event. That's why i decided to simply grab the keyboard. I solved the problem now by simply putting the focus back to the line edit by hand when the task is finished. So i should be save for possible extensions in the future.